# Loading .csv file into HIVE produces a table with a single long row

Tags: csv, hive

I'm trying to load a .csv file on disk into Hive.

Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628658/hive-text-delimiter) on StackOverflow, I created the table using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
(
id_number STRING, 
country STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I then dumped the data from the file into Hive using the following query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH /mytable.csv OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mytable;
```

Unfortunately, the result table in hive consisted of a single row, where each element (shown below) is a smashed-together version of a row from the .csv file:

"aDXLS23M\tRussia"

I've been stuck on this for hours and can't figure out how to get hive to recognize the column separators in the .csv file.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\t` is tab-delimited.  try `... fields terminated by '\t'`

Comment: Hi, I tried replacing ',' by '\t', and unfortunately that did not fix the problem.

Comment: post your csv content. Just 3 to 4 lines is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in hive shell:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;

CREATE TABLE mytable (id_number STRING,country STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH /mytable.csv OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mytable;
```

Just replace `,` with `\t` in your create command. If possible post your csv contents.

If it still didn't work, try removing `overwrite` from load data command like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH /mytable.csv INTO TABLE mytable;
```

Answer (score -1):

To load .CSV data file into hive table

eg.
create table salary(yrsofexp decimal (10,2), salary decimal(10,2))
row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/Test/SalaryData.csv'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE salary;
```

it's loading perfectly